# Action of $G \times G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

If $V$ is a representation of $G$ and $V^{*}$ is the dual representation of $V$, then what is the action of $G \times G$ on the $G \times G$ module $V^{*} \otimes V$. That is, what is $(g,h) \cdot (v \otimes w)$. Is it, $gv \otimes hw$?

Comment: Yes. ${} {} {} {} $